# Can I make this 'if' condition shorter?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have this condition:

```
if (pt.left == anything || pt.left == null || pt.left == borders.left || borders.left == anything)
```

can I make it shorter? I'm thinking about something like this:

```
if(pt.left == (anything || null || borders.left) || borders.left == anything)
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: what is type of `anything` and `boarders.left`?

Comment: You could make an extension-method if the same condition is used elsewhere, otherwise no, C# does not have an “is-one-of” or “is-in” operator unlike some languages like SQL.

Comment: Probably this would boil down to if (true)

Comment: How about writing a seperate method which validates your object?

Comment: while the other answers may work, how readable do you want it? I see nothing wrong with the condition as written. Very clear as to what you're checking.

Comment: the variables are strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the elements in an array and use contains.

```
if((new string[]{anything, null, borders.left}).Contains(pt.left) || borders.left == anything)
```

or, putting outside the if:

```
var arr = new string[]{anything, null, borders.left};
if(arr.Contains(pt.left) || borders.left == anything)
```

or, with an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsIn<T>(this T obj, params T[] array)
    {
       return array.Contains(obj);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if(pt.left.IsIn(anything, null, borders.left) || borders.left == anything)
```

Comment: You could also create an overload to the extension as `public static bool IsIn<T>(this T obj, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, params T[] array){return array.Contains(obj, comparer);}` so you can pass a custom equality comparer.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean this up making an extension method:

```
//I'm assuming you need value equality
public static bool EqualsOneOf<T>(
    this T value,
    T option1,
    T option2,
    params T[] options)
    where T: IEquatable<T>
{
    if (value.Equals(option1))
        return true;

    if (value.Equals(option2))
        return true;

    if (options != null && options.Contains(value))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

And now, your expression would be:

```
if(pt.left.EqualsOneOf(anything, null, borders.left) || borders.left == anything)
```

Comment: If you want a generic implementation I would advise on using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` instead of forcing `T` to implement `IEquatable<T>`. That's a more general solution.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Very good point, I'll leave it as it is and let the OP decide if he needs to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I've edited that into my answer but then deleted it and upvoted Magnetron's because `Array.Contains` is a better solution IMHO.